# SharePoint Sites.ExportWeb return values

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I'm playing with the [Sites.ExportWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sites.sites.exportweb.aspx) service in SharePoint, and I've gotten it to the point of returning an integer value.

My problem is I can't find any documentation anywhere about what these return values mean!

My C# code is below, the return value I'm getting is 5, but obviously I need to know what all possible return values mean :)

```
SitesWebReference.Sites siteservice = new SitesWebReference.Sites();
siteservice.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

int ret = siteservice.ExportWeb("exportJob", source, "http://sharepoint/sites/MySite/Export", true, true, false, 1000);
```

Would anyone know or have what the return values from ExportWeb and its friend ImportWeb actually mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I've stumbled upon this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313065.aspx

To summarise:

**ExportWebResult**

```
1 - Pending // The operation is in progress
4 - InvalidExportUrl // The site specified in the webUrl is not accessible
5 - ExportFileNoAccess // The location specified in the dataPath is not accessible
6 - ExportWebNoAccess // The user does not have the open web permission and manage web permission in order to execute this operation successfully
7 - ExportError // An error other than the errors  listed in this table occurred during exporting the site
8 - UploadDataError // The content migration package file is not uploaded to the server successfully
```

**ImportWebResult**:

```
1 - Pending // The operation is in progress.  
2 - GenericError // An error other than the errors listed in this table occurred importing the site.  
4 - InvalidImportUrl // The site specified in the webUrl is not accessible.  
5 - ImportFileNoAccess // At least one location specified in dataFiles i s not accessible.  
6 - ImportWebNoAccess // The user has insufficient permission to import to  the location specified in webUrl. 
8 - ImportWebNotEmpty // The location specified by webUrl corresponds to an existing site  that is not a blank site.  
11 - LogFileNoAccess // The location specified by  logPath is not accessible.
```

Sorry about the code view for the quotes, I was having an argument with the preview screen.